# Build simple iOS app with text field that prints value using NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nslog

I'm trying to learn Objective C and iOS development, but am having trouble. I am trying to create a very basic app that has a text field and that prints out the value entered into the text field using NSLog when the return key is pressed. I have added the text field via storyboard, but am unsure how to create the delegate method needed to make this work. I have thus far added the following code to the **ViewController.h** file: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfld;`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No "delegate method" is needed. What you need is an outlet. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Comment: show your code where are you doing `NSLog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `delegate` of the `UITextField` outlet to be your `ViewController`. Then have your `ViewController` implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Then in the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method, print out the `text` property of the `textView` input.

*Update*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.txtField.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Hi - how can I check whether I have set the delegate of the UITextfield outlet to be the ViewController? I think I have done this already, but am not sure tbh

Comment: @user3525783 _Questions?_

Comment: Add this. `@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>` Then implement `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Here's the docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:

Comment: FYI `UITextViewDelegate` has an even better method if you want to see the `NSLog` any time the text changes. `textViewDidChange`. But you need to use a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField`.

Comment: Hi - so I think I have implemented your comments, but the text is not showing up. Can you advise? I have added - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textfld {
 
    NSLog(@"text is : %@",textfld.text);
    
} 

Do i need something more to get it to display when the return key is pressed?

Comment: Is the method being called at all? Did set the delegate of the textField in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I believe I did set the delegate of the textField in viewDidLoad: @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textfld.delegate = self;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

Comment: Also in viewController.m is: 

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textfld {
 
    NSLog(@"text is : %@",textfld.text);
    
}

Comment: Check to make sure textField is not nil when you set it's delegate.   Also, that method will only be called when you END editing. Try dismissing the keyboard to test.

Comment: Sorry how do I write the code for the nil case? I don't understand the comments?

Comment: Are you using xcode? Add a breakpoint on that line and see if the textField is nil.

Comment: Update your question with a link. Somebody will take a look.

Comment: Noticed you took down the link. Did you figure it out?